# HTML Form not shrinking with div on resize

Tags: html, css, resize, shrinkwrap

I have 2 floated divs, one on the left, the other on the right, the left floated div has a form in it with input fields. However, i find that when i resize the page, the floated divs shrinks, but the form does not shrink with it, and in turn expands OUTSIDE of its floated parent, i have tried setting max height to form, all the parents have specific heights, but it does not seem to be working. Any suggestions?

```
                    <div class="12u formside">
                                <form id="ideaform">
                           <div class="row 50%">
                                        <div class="6u">
                            <input type="text" name="ideaname" id="name" placeholder="Give Your Idea A Title"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="6u 12u(3)">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                            <div class="row 50%">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" placeholder="Video Link" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="row 50%">
                                        <div class="12u">

                    <select id="select" name="select2">
                    <option selected disabled>Choose The Category Your Idea Falls Under</option>
                      <option value="science">Technology (E.G Code, Engineering)</option>
                      <option value="business">Business</option>
                      <option value="community">Community Related</option>
                      <option value="sports">Sports</option>
                      <option value="environment">Environment</option>
                      <option value="food">Food</option>
                      <option value="others">Others</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
                                    </div>

                                            <div class="row 50%">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <textarea maxlength="200" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Give a Short Descrition of Your Idea" rows="6"></textarea>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                     </form>


                    </div>

                    <div class="12u fileside">

                    </div>





            </section>
```

I have tried using overflow hidden but that will hide the form fields.

[image]

As you can see, when screen is minimized, the form expands beyond its parent, intruding into bottom div.

Comment: some css or a fiddle could come in handy

Comment: Every think just looks working .. http://jsfiddle.net/y9yL58pm/
Could you clarify your problem and what are you working on ..

Comment: there are two floated divs, one on left, the other on right, this form is in the left one. however when floating div is resized, the form expands instead of shrinking, and expands OUT of the parent div